# Python Loop through url json data not storing the results for loop

Tags: python, json, pandas

Trying to loop through the json results from a url then print the results only if there is a change since the last result every 1 minute. Everything works except the results are just being re-written over so it always shows 'nothing changed'.

```
import time
import sys
import pandas as pd


def main():
    result = []
    print('Checking for available  campsites....')


    url = "https://api.reserve.albertaparks.ca/api/public/campgrounds/67/availability?campingType=campsite" \
          "&arrivalDt=01-Aug-2021&departureDt=13-Sept-2021&unitSize=40&siteType=VEH"
    result = pd.read_json(url)


    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(result['availability'])
    df = df[df['available'] == True]
    df = df[df['fcfs'] == False]
    df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    print(df)

res_before = ""
while True:
    res = main()
    if res != res_before:
        print(res)
        res_before = res

    else:
        print("nothing changed")
    # time.sleep(300)

    for i in range(60):
        msg = "Pausing for 1 minute"
        sys.stdout.write("\r{} {} seconds ".format(msg, i))
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

```
             available   fcfs
date                         
01-Aug-2021       True  False
02-Aug-2021       True  False
03-Aug-2021       True  False
04-Aug-2021       True  False
05-Aug-2021       True  False
06-Aug-2021       True  False
07-Aug-2021       True  False
08-Aug-2021       True  False
09-Aug-2021       True  False
10-Aug-2021       True  False
Checking for available  campsites....
None
Pausing for 1 minute 59 seconds Checking for available  campsites....
nothing changed
```

Comment: Have you checked the formatting of the code in your question ? As it stands, the `main` function has only two lines inside it, reading json from the url is **not** inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Praveen noted, you didn't return anything from your function. Below is a section of code with a couple changes that make your code run correctly. See commented lines for needed changes.

```
    df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    print(df)
    return df #>>>> return dataframe

res_before = pd.DataFrame()  #>>>> want to compare dataframes correctly
while True:
    res = main()
    if not res.equals(res_before): #>>>> want to compare dataframes correctly
        print(res)
        res_before = res
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not return anything from the main() function. So, you can't assign a function as a value to a variable

Comment: I fixed the formatting for the main function but the results are still not being stored in a variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you